# Fundamental group computation (specific examples)

Tags: algebraic-topology

In lectures, we have shown that the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is $\{0\}$ and $S^1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. I was wondering how one might go about computing the fundamental groups of more complicated spaces, such as $S^1 \times D^2$ and $S^1 \times S^1$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The fundamental group functor preserves products.

Comment: Read some more questions at MSE, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234387/examples-of-fundamental-groups) for more interesting examples, such as the figure eight space: $\pi_1( S^1 \vee S^1) =\mathbb Z \ast \mathbb Z$. Direct products are not too interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Computations of fundamental group can be quite difficult. Some techniques include:

1. The seifert-van Kampen Theorem
2. Long Exact Sequence of Fibration
3. Passing to the universal cover.

In your cases, these all follow from the fact that [$\pi_1(X \times Y)\cong \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291311/the-fundamental-group-of-a-product-is-the-product-of-the-fundamental-groups-of-t/1020856#1020856) for path connected spaces. This follows essentially by checking a bijection by using projection maps, and that a continuous map in $X \times Y$ is continuous if and only if it is continuous in each factor.

Comment: It's probably important to point out that $X$ and $Y$ have to be path connected for $\pi_1(X \times Y) \cong \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y)$ to hold.

Comment: Agreed.${}{}{}$

Comment: Other techniques: homotopy equivalence ($S^1\times D^2$ deformation retracts onto $S^1$) and CW decomposition ($S^1\times S^1$ has a CW structure of a point, two circles, and disc; the circles generate $\pi_1$ and the discs give relations).